# QUERY SQL error unkown

Tags: sql, join, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT etape.ID_Expedition
      ,nmbr 
FROM (select etape.ID_Expedition
            ,count(etape.ID_Expedition) as nmbr 
      from etape 
      INNER JOIN Expedition on Expedition.numero=nmbr
      group by etape.ID_Expedition) as sub1 
ORDER BY nmbr DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The error **nmbr** is unkown , but i am saying AS nmbr if i remove the inner join it works correctly

`INNER JOIN Expedition on Expedition.numero=nmbr`

the problem is here, it don't recognize nmbr.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This part "INNER JOIN Expedition on Expedition.numero=nmbr" is not correct. It should be "on Expedition.numero=tablename.columnName "

Comment: What would you even be attempting to use a `count(*)` for a join condition?

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is doing all the work you need.  Just use:

```
select e.ID_Expedition, count(*) as nmbr
from etape e
group by e.ID_Expedition
order by nmbr DESC
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to express the following:

```
SELECT sub1.ID_Expedition ,sub1.nmbr 
FROM 
(   select etape.ID_Expedition ,count(etape.ID_Expedition) as nmbr 
    from etape 
    group by etape.ID_Expedition
) 
as sub1 
INNER JOIN Expedition on Expedition.numero=sub1.nmbr
ORDER BY nmbr DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT ID_Expedition,nmbr
FROM 
( select etape.ID_Expedition ,count(etape.ID_Expedition) as nmbr 
  from etape 
  group by etape.ID_Expedition ) as sub1 
INNER JOIN Expedition on Expedition.numero=sub1.nmbr
ORDER BY ..
```